# Are IELTS past tests available for students preparing for the exam?

Tags: language-exams, ielts

1. I want to know a way to find past IELTS questions. If they are available freely?
2. Are there good exams for all modules? (Specially Listening)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the books available in which some preparation exams (sample tests and past tests) are published and you can study those exams and sample tests. Some of these books and preparation materials are available in [How do I prepare?](http://www.ielts.org/test_takers_information/how_do_i_prepare.aspx) page on [IELTS official website](http://www.ielts.org/), [Cambridge English Exams and IELTS books](http://www.cambridge.org/us/cambridgeenglish/catalog/cambridge-english-exams-ielts) and [books about IELTS by other publishers](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=ielts&gws_rd=ssl).

If you are seeking for free online sample exams and studying materials, there are some preparation materials for exam available in different websites over the net, which you can find by a [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ielts%20free%20sample%20test).

Answer (score 1):

It is well worth investing in at least one [IELTS past examination book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_4_6?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=ielts%20practice%20tests&sprefix=IELTS%20%2Cundefined%2C407&crid=J7FY3J3749S0), make sure the CD is included in the price otherwise you'll have to pay for it separately and that single CD can be ridiculously high-priced.

A word of warning for candidates who are self-studying,  some IELTS websites are truly awful. Their suggested sample essays, for example,  are an embarrassment and should not be touched with a barge pole.

On the other hand, there are professionals who genuinely care, and are also native speakers. [**Flo-Joe**](http://www.flo-joe.com/ielts.htm) and [**IELTS Liz**](http://ieltsliz.com/) are among the best in my experience. Liz's videos, especially, are very useful, clear, and straightforward.

I am not affiliated with either website. But I have used these resources in private lessons to help Italian candidates pass their exams, or obtain that elusive 7.0 grade (IELTS).

Answer (score 0):

You can find some practice tests for each module [here](http://takeielts.britishcouncil.org/prepare-test/free-practice-tests).
Even though they're not free you might want to consider buying books, including [official practice materials](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Official-IELTS-Practice-Materials-Audio/dp/1906438463/ref=sr_1_16?ie=UTF8&qid=1497566231&sr=8-16&keywords=ielts).

And of course, as it has already been mentioned, a quick simple search on any search engine might give you enough preparation materials.